# Is the following use of "nonetheless" correct?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

> I was so down and unmotivated, **nonetheless**, that even thinking about
>   getting up the chair seemed like a tedious and burdensome task.

I'm having my doubts because at first I used *however*, and know, well, I'm not very sure anymore.

Comment: I would suggest your original *however* here.  Really, though, the necessary context for even the use of *however* is missing. (Hopefully it's in the previous sentence).

Comment: Use *nonetheless* (for example) when saying that your opinion or resolve to do something has not been diminished even in the face of opposition or adverse evidence.  *All of his team members voted against him but Tom liked them all nonetheless.*

Comment: Jim's spot-on. The bottom line is no, *nonetheless* is not appropriate there.

Comment: You just seemed to have continued the thought process after the first *sentence* (not clause): "I was so down and unmotivated. Nonetheless,  ...." However, the sentence is ambiguous: what does *nonetheless* refer back to? The state of being "down and unmotiviated?" or something mentioned earlier? Do you just mean to say ***yet*** perhaps?

Comment: The phrase “getting up the chair” is obscure.  Do you mean “getting up **from** the chair”?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*nonetheless* is most often used as a replacement for *however, in spite of* or *despite that* so it doesn't sit well in your sentence.

For *nonetheless* to be useful in your sentence, the second part really has to be in opposition to the first as in *I was so down and unmotivated, nonetheless, I clambered on to the chair with the spriteliness of a chimp.*

Or a preceding sentence is in opposition such as *I'd just won the lottery but I was so down and unmotivated nonetheless.*

*so much so* would work better in your sentence.

> I was so down and unmotivated, so much so, that even thinking about getting up the chair seemed like a tedious and burdensome task.